# Dynamic polling with swrv in vue3

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to poll an endpoint with varying refreshIntervals. For instance, it starts with 5 seconds and then it changes to 10 seconds by pressing a button in the UI.

I'm using [swrv](https://github.com/Kong/swrv) but I'm not able to create a dependency that triggers the refreshInterval to change. How could I do this?

I assumed it should look something like this and I'd put a dependency somewhere:

```js
const { data, error } = useSWRV("some key", fetcher, {
  refreshInterval: <dynamic value>,
});
```

Comment: Checking how it works may give faster results than a low-profile question, https://github.com/Kong/swrv/blob/master/src/use-swrv.ts#L307-L329 . You can see that it's not dynamic but you can reimplement refresh interval the way you want similarly to the original

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. I implemented it without using swrv, but with that also lost the functionality encapsulated there. I suppose it could be a good feature to request to the library maintainers.